# Is it possible to change the wallpaper in Windows 7 Starter?

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the wallpaper in Windows 7 Starter Edition](https://superuser.com/questions/69601/how-to-change-the-wallpaper-in-windows-7-starter-edition)

I looked for every possibility to change the desktop wallpaper but to vain, so can u please suggest me any type of software that can help me change my desktop wallpaper?????