# Window 7 Background Bypass

Tags: windows-7, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the wallpaper of Windows 7 Starter Edition?](https://superuser.com/questions/69601/how-do-i-change-the-wallpaper-of-windows-7-starter-edition)

Is there a way to bypass the limitations of Windows 7 Starter to allow the use of a personalized background?